# How can I send additional parameters through SNS push notifications for ASPN?

Tags: node.js, apple-push-notifications, amazon-sns

I'm sending push notifications for android and iOS using SNS with nodejs (GCM, APNS). My payload looks like this:

```
    const payload = {
      default: body,
      GCM: {
        notification: {
          body,
          title,
        },
        data: {
          type
        },
      },
      APNS: {
        aps: {
          alert: {
            title,
            body,
          },
        },
        data: {
          type
        },
      },
    };

    payload.GCM = JSON.stringify(payload.GCM);
    payload.APNS = JSON.stringify(payload.APNS);

    return JSON.stringify(payload);
```

The mobile devices are getting the notifications with title and body but the type inside data is not present in the object for APNS. Is the object structure wrong?

Answer (score 0):

For `APNS`, you could try unpacking your data object like so:

```
    const payload = {
      default: body,
      GCM: {
        notification: {
          body,
          title,
        },
        data: {
          type
        },
      },
      APNS: {
        aps: {
          alert: {
            title,
            body,
          },
        },
        type,
      },
    };
```

Couldn't find any solid answers but everything I've read on this topic suggests that APNS JSON payload only supports custom **string** key value pairs outside of the `"aps"` object:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-send-custom-platform-specific-payloads-mobile-devices.html

eg.

```
{
  "APNS": "{\"aps\":{\"content-available\":1},\"Foo1\":\"Bar\",\"Foo2\":123}"
}
```

eg.

```
 'APNS' : JSON.stringify({
   'aps' : { 
     'alert' : $title,
     'badge' : '0',
     'sound' : 'default'
   },
   'id' : '123',
   's' : 'section',
}),
```